# How to get the pass for web folder

Tags: symfony

Normally I can use this kind of syntax for routing in twig.

```
{{ path('acme_top_root') }}
```

Now,I have a folder

```
/web/uploads/documents/
```

How can I get the pass for this folder?

It doesnt have the name defined in route.yml.

Comment: absolute or relative url desired? do you mean "path" by "pass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asset

```
{{ asset('uploads/documents/...') }}
```